# Is it possible to link different javers commits and fetch them together using a deep shadow scope or any other way?

Tags: javers

I'm looking for a feature in Javers, when creating a snapshot, to link it with other previously created snapshots.

I looked at the commit-deep scope for the shadows, but it is fetching only the snapshots which have the same commit id.

I want something like this:

Entity Employee is linked oneToOne with Entity Address.
I save an address which stores an Address snapshot A1 with commit c1.
Now I save an employee linking to that address which stores an Employee snapshot E1 with commit c2.

I am not able to fetch these two snapshots A1 and E1 together as they are in different commits (c1 and c2).

Is it possible to get this info with the current Javers or do we need to add a feature for this or is this an over-kill?

The feature can be like this:

If I query for shadows of Employees (byInstanceId say) with a new scope (may be like linked-deep scope), it should give me all shadows of the Employee using commit-deep , plus all the linked shadows, in this case, both snapshots E1 and A1

This way, we can track what address the employee had at a point in history.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `Deep+` Shadow Scope.

see https://javers.org/documentation/jql-examples/#query-for-shadows

There are four scopes. The wider the scope, the more object shadows are loaded to the resulting graph (and the more database queries are executed). Scopes are defined in the ShadowScope enum.

- Shallow — the defult scope — Shadows are created only from snapshots selected directly in the main JQL query.
- Child-value-object — JaVers loads all child Value Objects owned by selected Entities. Since 3.7.5, this scope is implicitly enabled for all Shadow queries and can’t be disabled.
- Commit-deep — Shadows are created from all snapshots saved in commits touched by the main query.
- Deep+ — JaVers tries to restore full object graphs with (possibly) all objects loaded.